# Disable lowercasing through 'u'

Tags: key-bindings

I don't look at my keyboard when I type (I don't think a lot of people do these days) and I catch myself occasionally pressing 'u' in visual mode by mistake.

This causes all the text in a visual bloc to go lower case.

It's happened multiple times and I would really want to disable this functionality. I am aware that I can use `~` to change case.

How can I disable `u` during visual mode (lowercasing) but not `u` (undo)?

Answer (score 3):

You can map `u` to a no-op in visual mode with the following.

```
:vmap u <Nop>
```

That won't affect the behavior of `u` in normal mode. See

```
:help <Nop>
:help map-modes
```

Comment: That should be visual and select mode. xmap is visual mode only.